# How to check function decorators in Python

Tags: python, flask, decorator, python-decorators, flask-login

I'm building a website using the (awesome) [Flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/) in which some of the routes are protected by a [flask-login](http://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) `@login_required` decorator like this:

```
@app.route('/awesomepage')
@login_required  # <-- this is what I mean
def awesome_page():
    return render_template('awesome.html')
```

When somebody logs out he is normally redirected to the page he was viewing when he pressed logout. But when a person logs out from a page he needs to be logged in for (i.e. which has a `@login_required` decorator) he gets a 401 Unauthorized error after logging out. So when redirecting users back to the original page, I want to check whether the page from which they were coming has a `@login_required` decorator and if so, redirect them to the front page.

My current logout view looks like this:

```
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    next_url = request.args.get('next') or request.referrer or url_for('index')
    return redirect(next_url)
```

So in this code I want to check whether `request.referrer` has a `@login_required` decorator. Does anybody know how I can do that? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Can't you circumvent this problem by [setting a login view](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#customizing-the-login-process) and having users being redirected there instead of throwing a 401?

Comment: If *all* of the decorated methods are inside a class, you can lookup their line number for their first line of code which changes if they are decorated but this is a very strange way of doing things :) Basically you can keep a dictionary of line numbers that corresponds to the first line number of a decorator function's code and then use that to "map" functions to their decorators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot, not easily.

The better option is to tell the page to include a better `next` value in the logout link by explicitly setting a `login_required` flag in the template:

```
@app.route('/awesomepage')
@login_required
def awesome_page():
    return render_template('awesome.html', login_required=True)
```

and render the logout link with:

```html
{% if login_required %}{{ url_for('logout', next=url_for('index')) }}
{% else %}{{ url_for('logout' }}{% endif %}
```

The alternative would be to have a login view defined, and have `login_required` redirect to that view. That *could* be your index page.

The alternative would be for you to create an augmented `login_required` decorator that sets a global you then test for:

```
from functools import wraps

from flask import g
from flask_login import login_required

def my_login_required(f):
    @login_required
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        g.login_required = True
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

then use that decorator on your views instead of the Flask-Login version:

```
@app.route('/awesomepage')
@my_login_required
def awesome_page():
    return render_template('awesome.html')
```

and update the template to look for the global:

```html
{% if g.login_required %}{{ url_for('logout', next=url_for('index')) }}
{% else %}{{ url_for('logout' }}{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hmm, good idea but that leaves room for errors because of the duplication. If I then change remove or add a `@login_required` I always have to remember to change the `login_required=True` in the render_template as well. Is there no other way to somehow automate that?

Comment: @kramer65: I've added a custom decorator option for you.

Comment: That is awesome! Totally solves the whole issue. Thanks a million!